# Tikz Subfigure (\includegraphics) overlaps with text

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlap

I have created a tikz figure entailing 3 subfigures in 2 rows. The first row entails an image while the other has two bar graphs next to each other.

My **problem**: The imported image overlaps with the text above the figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{Example}
\author{Name }
\date{April 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

    \begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=7cm]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig:sub1}
    \end{subfigure}
    }
    \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    domain=0:1,
    every axis plot/.append style={no markers},
    %xlabel=Timepoints (d),
    ylabel= Label,
    width=\linewidth,
    height=7cm,
    ymax=700,
    ymin=150,
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=1.5,
    xticklabels={DIV15, DIV17},xtick={0,1},
    x tick label style={rotate=90}, 
    legend style={at={(0.45,0.78)},anchor=west}]
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit]
    coordinates {
    (0,490.40) +- (23.86,23.86) 
    (1,376.00) +- (22.19,22.19) 
    };
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,386.30) +- (41.29,41.29) 
    (1,329.90) +- (32.07,32.07)
    };  
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,424.60) +- (24.90,24.90) 
    (1,334.90) +- (20.09,20.09)
    };  
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,263.2) +- (33.89,33.89) 
    (1,228.00) +- (30.67,30.67)
    };  
\node [above, font=\Large] at (axis cs: 0.21,300) {$\ast$}; 
\node [above, font=\Large] at (axis cs: 1.21,265) {$\ast$}; 
\legend{1,2,3,4}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   

    \end{subfigure}\hspace{8mm}
    
    
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    %bar width=.45cm,
    domain=0:1,
    every axis plot/.append style={no markers},
    ylabel= Label,
    width=\linewidth,
    height=7cm,
    ymax=7,
    ymin=0,
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=1.5,
    xticklabels={DIV15, DIV17},xtick={0,1},
    x tick label style={rotate=90}, 
    legend style={at={(0.45,0.78)},anchor=west}]
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit]
    coordinates {
    (0,3.69) +- (0.17,0.17) 
    (1,4.16) +- (0.28,0.28) 
    };
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,3.29) +- (0.31,0.31) 
    (1,3.36) +- (0.26,0.26)
    };  
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,3.70) +- (0.11,0.11) 
    (1,4.10) +- (0.25,0.25)
    };  
\addplot+[fill,error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,y explicit] 
    coordinates {
    (0,2.32) +- (0.30,0.30) 
    (1,3.11) +- (0.25,0.25)
    };  
\node [above, font=\Large] at (axis cs: 0.21,2.8) {$\ast$}; 
\node [above, font=\Large] at (axis cs: 1.21,3.6) {$\ast$}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
    \end{subfigure}}
    \caption[Caption]{Caption\\
\footnotesize{\textit{Note.}}}
    \label{fig:3.5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please extend this to a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Additionally we don't have access to the image you use, either use `\rule{width}{height}` or use one of the images that comes with the `mwe` package

Comment: Thank you! Edits have been made :)

Comment: This example is not compilable. I cannot copy this and compile it without adding anything, please update. There are no `\begin/end{document}`

Comment: And please don't use class that is not publically available. There is no `MastersDoctoralThesis` on ctan. Use `article` or similar instead

Comment: You cannot resize stuff the way you are trying to

Comment: Where does `cycle list name=colorbrewer-blues` come from?

Comment: Please start over, make this compile without errors and then deal with overflow. Having others debug your compilation errors is a bit of a waste of our time, sorry.

Comment: What's the point of using a tikzpicture environment for `\includegraphics{…}`?

Comment: Additionally two `\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}` with 8mm between them makes no sense. That adds up to more than `\linewidth`. Try `0.45\linewidth` and replace `\hspace{8mm}` with `\hfill`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The code should now be comoileable. My apologies, I am a bit new to this.

Comment: No, it still does not compile without errors? Are you using overleaf? a lot of overleaf users have a tendency to overlook compilation errors.

Comment: Oh yes, the colours weren't added, I had just looked after proper typesetting. I removed them now and it is error free. Thank you

Comment: Where exactly are there any overlap with text? There are no extra text in the example, thus the image you posted does not seem to come from the example.

Comment: The image posted is from my overleaf using the code provided above. There is overlay with text visible on the right side of the top subfigure.

Comment: There should be text from the lipsum package?